# Выборка из коллекции по определенным полям с ограничениями

Tags: java, сортировка, коллекции

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такую идею:

Есть лист продуктов:
`List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();`

Предположим, что их там миллион.

У продукта есть: id, name, price(float); У продуктов могут быть одинаковые id.

Необходимо сделать выборку из 1000 самых дешевых продуктов, но при этом в выборке должно быть не более 20 продуктов с одинаковым идентификатором.

Начал с сортировки цены:

```
products.sort(new Comparator<Product>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
                    return Float.compare(o1.getPrice(), o2.getPrice());
                }
            });
```

Если с сортировкой у меня правильно, подскажите, как в итоге можно сделать такую выборку с такими ограничениями? Больше вызывает смущения, как организовать проверку, чтобы  id в выборке  не повторялись более 20 раз.

Comment: `id` продукта должен указывать на конкретный продукт. Сама [концепция `id`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) об этом говорит. Лучше используйте что-то другое вместо `id` - это может серьезно запутать других программистов

Comment: не мои прихоти, таковы условия задачи. Спасибо Вам за совет!

Answer (score 0):

Пробегитесь с `Map<String, Integer>` по листу и подсчитайте, сколько по каждому `id` продуктов. Пробегаясь используйте переменную, которую увеличивайте с каждым новым элементом, входящим в мапу с менее 20 элементов. Выходите из цикла по достижении ей значения 1000(и по кол-ву просмотренных объектов, если не хотите получить бесконечный цикл в перспективе). После удалите все те пары ключ-значение(`id`-кол-во), у которых значение более 20(используйте `.entrySet()` для получения всех пар ключ-значение). Затем прогоните `n` элементов, проверяя, есть ли `id` в мапе. Если есть, то это искомый элемент.

P.S.: Для увеличения производительности можно сначала прогнать по мапе 1000 элементов, затем проверить мапу на превышение кол-ва элементов(20) каждого `id`, а потом продолжить прогонять(если такие превышения были) уже по выше описанному алгоритму.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int toGetContainers = 100;
    final int idCount = 10;
    final int criticalCount = 10;
    List<IDContainer> containers = new ArrayList<IDContainer>(toGetContainers * 3);
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(7);
    int countSeen = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < toGetContainers * 4; i++) {
        containers.add(new IDContainer(random.nextInt(idCount)));
    }
    for(int i = 0; countSeen < containers.size() && (i < toGetContainers); i++, countSeen++) {
        counter.put(containers.get(countSeen).getID(), counter.getOrDefault(containers.get(countSeen).getID(), 0) + 1);
        if(counter.get(containers.get(countSeen).getID()) > criticalCount) {
            i--;
        }
    }
    counter.entrySet().forEach((Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry) -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()));
    List<Integer> normalIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : counter.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue() <= criticalCount) {
            normalIDs.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    normalIDs.forEach((Integer id) -> System.out.println("normal id: " + id));
    List<IDContainer> withNormalID = new ArrayList<IDContainer>(countSeen);
    for(int i = 0; i < countSeen; i++) {
        if(normalIDs.contains(containers.get(i).getID())) {
            withNormalID.add(containers.get(i));
        }
    }
    withNormalID.forEach((IDContainer idContainer) -> System.out.println(idContainer.getID()));
    System.out.println(countSeen);



}

static class IDContainer {
    private int id;

    public IDContainer(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Вывод(Не должен совпадать - рандом же):

> 0 16
>   1 19
>   2 11
>   3 19
>   4 14
>   5 16
>   6 12
>   7 10
>   8 15
>   9 17
>   normal id: 7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   149

Comment: Подскажите, правильно ли мыслю?

 `Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();


        int num = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
               map.put(products.get(i).getId(),  map.getOrDefault(products.get(i).getId(), num) + 1);
               if (map.get(i) == 20) {
                   num = 0;
                   continue;
               }
               count++;
               if (count == 1000)
                   break;
            }
        return finalProds;
        }`


Не совсем понял вторую часть, когда использовать удаление

Comment: Попробовал еще такую структуру:

`for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {

                map.put(products.get(i).getId(), map.getOrDefault(products.get(i).getId(), num) + 1);
            }



            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){


            for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {


                Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = it.next();
                if (entry.getValue() > 20) {
                    it.remove();
                    i--;
                }
            }            
        }`

Comment: А как потом обратно из мапы, в которой уже хранятся нужные значения продуктов, сформировать (перетащить) в финальный List<Product> итоговые продукты по заданным параметрами?

Comment: @indie Справились?

Comment: ответил ответом к своему вопросу, так как в комментарии не помещается

Answer (score 0):

@miron
к сожалению, у меня не хватает пока знаний, чтобы легко воспринять то, что Вы мне посоветовали. Остановился пока на таком варианте:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
            map.put(products.get(i).getId(), map.getOrDefault(products.get(i).getId(), num) + 1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = it.next();
                if (entry.getValue() > 20) {
                    it.remove();
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                finalProds.add(products.get(i));
            }
        }
        return finalProds;
    }
```

Comment: Немного накосячил при объяснении алгоритма. Выложил рабочую демку